# copy folder to multiple servers with different %userprofile%

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, windows-server-2008, batch-processing

I do not have access to GPO or AD/OU, so what I found to do the easiest was to create a batch file for users.

Here is what I want to achieve :

I have over 50 servers, and 10 users that will be connecting to these machines. 
On those different machines, I want to populate, from 1 location (1 main server, 1 main location/main user), all the internet favorites (C:\Users\MAIN USER\Favorites\Links) to everyone on every machine...

I want to create a batch file, with minimum user manipulation, . So basicly, I will give the batch file to the 10 users, and they could launch it on 1 machine, and populate the links from their %USERPROFILE%, from the location of their choice.

I started figuring something with xcopy, but would like your advice/help on completing it.

```
    xcopy "\\NAMEOFMACHINE\C$\Users\MAIN USER\Favorites\Links" 
    "\\serverlist.txt\C$\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Links" /E /I
```

I think this could be the easiest way to do so. As the initial location will be updated monthly with new links...

Answer (score 0):

if the user is running it then this should mirror the source to the target folder, making them identical.

```
@echo off
robocopy "\\NAMEOFMACHINE\C$\Users\MAIN USER\Favorites\Links"  "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Links" /mir
```

Comment: Ok, I have 2 questions then:

1- What would be the difference in the code, if I (the admin) would populate the code, and push the links to every user ?

2- How could I insert a "all server list.txt" in this code, so the links would be on all the 50 machines, either userbased or with me (admin).

Comment: AFAIK Stack Overflow requires that you open a new thread if you change the question that requires a different answer.