# Batch copy files from list of server

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-server-2008

From this line of code :

```
robocopy "\\NAMEOFMACHINE\C$\Users\MAIN USER\Favorites\Links"  "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Links" /mir
```

I want to have to possibility to add a list of server to push this "copy".

So in reality, I want to create a batch file, to push over 50 machine, all my Favorites, from list.txt (where all servers would be stored).

Comment: This question started with this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596640/copy-folder-to-multiple-servers-with-different-userprofile

Comment: if you make good questions you will get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do robocopy "%%~a" "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Links" /mir
```

Comment: Actually, the list.txt contains the list of ALL the servers on which I want to "push" the links.  Now, I wonder where I include the original path ?

What I want is to copy from 1 location, some files, and push them to ALL users, on the list.txt servers.